# Filter effecting measure in unexpected way

Tags: powerbi, dax

Having what appears to be inconsistent behavior on how a filter is effecting my visual. Need help finding what might be different. I'm recreating a report with updated data and I'm trying to create a clustered column chart with last years data as the secondary column. Here are my DAX measures (PYClaimCount):

```
calculate(count(SAFETYDATABYDRIVER[Claim_Number]),SAMEPERIODLASTYEAR('CALENDAR'[Day]))
```

original report:

```
calculate(count(DriverFact[C&K Claim Number]),SAMEPERIODLASTYEAR('Calendar Table'[Day]))
```

Measure is just cut and paste with the table and column names but for some reason my version is treating the measure differently. See tables below. Let me know If I should to add anything else.

[My Visualization as table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/22GhT.png)
[Original Visualization B as table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2I7p4.png)

Comment: You are getting your data from different table, it might be this has different data or you have not the same relation between the 2 tables of the original. Relation is the 3rd imagebutton on left..

Comment: @Aldert Relationships are the same. I don't see how slightly different data would create these results. Did you see the screenshots?

Comment: Yes, this is why I made the comment: One column has data from 2019, the other from 2020..